# recvmsg() returns "Resource temporarily unavailable"

Tags: c, linux

I am using a Linux machine, and am sending UDP packets.

I want to get the hardware timestamp on the NIC for the transmitted packets. I have seen other posts and have set up the appropriate flags.

```
int flag = SOF_TIMESTAMPING_TX_HARDWARE | SOF_TIMESTAMPING_RAW_HARDWARE;
```

I'm using:

```
int rc = recvmsg(fd, MSG_ERRQUEUE);
```

However, `recvmsg()` seems to return `"Resource temporarily unavailable"`.
I call this function after waiting 50 microsec, and retry 5 times.
I was able to get the hardware timestamps with the same code, but now am encountering this issue without changing anything.

Any ideas on what I should look into that may be causing this issue?

Comment: Is the socket in non-blocking mode? That error code just means that there's nothing currently available to read and you told it not to wait for input.

Comment: @Smiley7 – If you really are _using:

`int rc = recvmsg(fd, MSG_ERRQUEUE);`_, you are missing the second argument.

Answer (score 2):

In `linux/Documentation/networking/timestamping.txt`, there's this note regarding reading transmit timestamps from the error queue:

> 2.1.1.5 Blocking Read
>
> Reading from the error queue is always a non-blocking operation. To
>       block waiting on a timestamp, use poll or select. poll() will return
>       POLLERR in pollfd.revents if any data is ready on the error queue.
>       There is no need to pass this flag in pollfd.events. This flag is
>       ignored on request. See also "man 2 poll".

So, regardless of whether or not the socket is in non-blocking mode, it looks like you'll get the indicated error if the error queue is empty (i.e., because the packet hasn't been transmitted yet, so the timestamp hasn't been queued).

My best guess is that you're running into a situation where the packets are being queued for transmission for more than 50usec for whatever reason (other outgoing traffic, maybe contention on the wire, waiting for an ARP response), so you're missing the timestamp by giving up too soon.  I'd suggest polling with a larger timeout and see if that fixes the issue.